# Retina display images in app?

Tags: plist, retina-display

It was my understanding that all you needed to support retina display was to have a @2x image and scale down to half for the non retina display devices.  I put all the regular and @2x files in my Supporting Files > Images folder.  However, on the apple website is says the following:

"Even if you use these fixed icon filenames, your app should continue to include the      CFBundleIcons or CFBundleIconFiles key in your app’s Info.plist file"

I was unaware that I had to do anything to the plist file or maybe the information in apple's website is outdated. I am running xcode 4.4, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its simple to add icons click on your project in the xcode navigator and just drag and drop the icons to the right slots. then, to be sure they are there just click on the info tab icon files ios5, icon files, ... , and then see if it says icon.png, icon@2x.png, icon-72.png because you need those. its pretty simple and the only editing you really have to do is add icon-72.png(which should be 72x72) and then it should work fine

Comment: Ok, I see they get automatically added to the plist file, the iTunesArtwork does too.  Do you know about the search results icon? I added them as Icon-Small.png and Icon-Small@2x.png to my project.  They don't seem to show up anywhere.  Is it fine to just have them in my file bundle and Apple will pick them up there?